# Stumped on how to make local variables (colorSelect1, colorSelect2) global so that I can execute the logic statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, global, local

I'm having difficulty determining why this fails to execute. When I consoloe.log the colorSelect variables, they return the correct value. However, i believe the disconnect is that the variables are created within the function and therefore are not recognized as global which negates my logic statement. Any suggestions on how to circumvent this issue?

```js
var colorSelect1 = null;
var colorSelect2 = null;

 //selecting the first color
$(function() {
    $(".color1").click(function() {
      $(".color1").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color");
      console.log(colorSelect1);
      return colorSelect1;
    });
  })
  //selecting the second color
 $(function() {
  $(".color2").click(function() {
    $(".color2").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var colorSelect2 = $(this).css("background-color");
    console.log(colorSelect2);
    return colorSelect2;
  });
})

 // making a new color based upon the two color selections
if (colorSelect1 === "red" && colorSelect2 === "yellow") {
  console.log("We have orange!");
  $(".colorCombo").css('background-color', 'orange');
}
```

```css
.all-divs {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.active {
  border: 2px solid;
}
.colorCombo {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 393px;
}
.group1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.group2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
#red1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#blue1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#yellow1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#red2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#blue2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#yellow2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Please select a color.
</div>
<div class="all-divs">

  <div class="group1">

    <div class="color1" id="red1">

    </div>
    <div class="color1" id="blue1">

    </div>
    <div class="color1" id="yellow1">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group2">
    <div class="color2" id="red2">

    </div>
    <div class="color2" id="blue2">

    </div>
    <div class="color2" id="yellow2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorCombo">

</div>
```

Comment: remove the `var ` in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have <s>two</s> three problems here and your code will only work if all three are fixed.

**Problem 1:** as you have correctly surmised, you are only affecting variables within your functions.

To remedy this, remove the `var` before these variables inside these functions:

```
colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color");

colorSelect2 = $(this).css("background-color");
```

This will cause these variable names to reference the variables in the outer scope instead of just within the functions.

**Problem 2:** your `if` statement executes long before any of these events takes place. It is not continually evaluated as the variables' values change.

To fix this, you can put your `if` statement inside a function of its own:

```
function checkColors() {
    if(colorSelect1 === "red" && colorSelect2 === "yellow"){
        console.log("We have orange!");
        $(".colorCombo").css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
}
```

And call it in each of your events:

```
$(".color1").click(function() {
    $(".color1").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color");
    checkColors();
});
```

**Problem 3:** Using `.css('background-color')` will not necessarily give you exactly the same value specified in your CSS. For example, in Chrome, calling it on an element with a `red` background will result in the value `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

One way to remedy this is to use `data-` on your elements to specify the values you need, and then retrieve them with `.data()`:

```
<div class="color1" id="red1" data-color="red">

colorSelect1 = $(this).data('color');
```

Lastly, while not related to the problem you are having, you are using `header` and `footer` incorrectly. The tag you have named as `header` should be named `head`, and you should remove the `footer`, since footers should only appear *inside* the `body` element, and there's no point in having one if it's empty.

Full solution, with some other improvements:

```js
var colorSelect1 = null;
var colorSelect2 = null;

$(function() {

  //selecting the first color
  $(".color1").click(function() {
    $(".color1").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    colorSelect1 = $(this).data("color");
    console.log(colorSelect1);
    checkColors();
  });

  //selecting the second color
  $(".color2").click(function() {
    $(".color2").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    colorSelect2 = $(this).data("color");
    console.log(colorSelect2);
    checkColors();
  });

});

// making a new color based upon the two color selections
function checkColors() {
  if(colorSelect1 === "red" && colorSelect2 === "yellow"){
    console.log("We have orange!");
    $(".colorCombo").css('background-color', 'orange');
  }
}
```

```css
.all-divs {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.active {
  border: 2px solid;
}
.colorCombo {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 393px;
}
.group1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.group2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.color1, .color2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
[data-color=red] {
  background-color: red;
}
[data-color=blue] {
  background-color: blue;
}
[data-color=yellow] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Please select a color.
</div>
<div class="all-divs">

  <div class="group1">

    <div class="color1" id="red1" data-color="red">

    </div>
    <div class="color1" id="blue1" data-color="blue">

    </div>
    <div class="color1" id="yellow1" data-color="yellow">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group2">
    <div class="color2" id="red2" data-color="red">

    </div>
    <div class="color2" id="blue2" data-color="blue">

    </div>
    <div class="color2" id="yellow2"  data-color="yellow">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="colorCombo">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was weary when I saw in my console.log request that the console did not return the colors ("red", "yellow", etc.) as you pointed out. Thanks for taking the time to explain each error and for providing a solution that works.

Comment: @pghInitechBranch Great! If this solved your issue, I would ask that you click the checkmark icon next to it to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

take var out of the function where you are assigning the values.
e.g. :

```
 $(".color1").click(function() {
     $(".color1").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color");
     console.log(colorSelect1);
     return colorSelect1;
   });
 })
```

Comment: What's with the -1 ? Wow.

Comment: This alone doesn't fix the asker's problem. It's only part of the solution.

Comment: so it part solves your issue, and therefore is useful. Therefore the "This answer is not useful" button is not fair dude.  If you want people to help you you have to be a little more receptive to their help.

Comment: @RichLinnell FWIW I'm not the OP, but I would argue that an answer is not useful if it only solves part of the problem described. Otherwise, SO would be littered with partial answers that addressed part of the problem and left it unsolved.

Comment: Whatevs. You're more SO ranked, so what do I know. Lesson learnt here. Don't add, just take.

Comment: @RichLinnell As of right now, you've netted +18 points for a minimal effort answer that only addresses a portion of the problem. I'd say it worked out well for you! FYI I do upvote answers when they fully address the OP's issue.

Comment: @RichLinnell Thanks for your answer. Not sure why you were down voted but I appreciate the input. It makes sense now as you explained it that removing var allowed for the variables to remain global.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `colorSelect1` and `colorSelect2` first as global and then redeclare them in the functions as local.
If you remove the var inside the functions it should work.

```
//selecting the first color
    $(function() {
         $(".color1").click(function() {
             $(".color1").removeClass('active');
             $(this).addClass('active');
             colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color");
             console.log(colorSelect1);
             return colorSelect1;
           });
         })
       //selecting the second color
       $(function()  {
          $(".color2").click(function() {
               $(".color2").removeClass('active');
               $(this).addClass('active');
               colorSelect2 = $(this).css("background-color");
               console.log(colorSelect2);
               return colorSelect2;
             });
           })
```

Comment: I voted you back up dude. Someone -1 us for answering the question correctly. I don't think they get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var colorSelect1 = null;
var colorSelect2 = null;

//selecting the first color
// this is your doc ready, just use one
$(function() {

     $(".color1").click(function() {
         $(".color1").removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
         colorSelect1 = $(this).css("background-color"); // remove var
         console.log(colorSelect1);
         return colorSelect1;
      });

    $(".color2").click(function() {
           $(".color2").removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           colorSelect2 = $(this).css("background-color"); // remove var
           console.log(colorSelect2);
           return colorSelect2;
         });

    // making a new color based upon the two color selections
    if(colorSelect1 === "red" && colorSelect2 === "yellow"){
        console.log("We have orange!");
        $(".colorCombo").css('background-color', 'orange');
     }

 }); //End Doc Ready
```

Remove *var*.  Var will make it a local variable inside enclosing function, when you remove it, it refers to the two you initialized outside of the doc ready.

Comment: I voted you back up dude. Someone -1 us for answering the question correctly. I don't think they get it